# Text outer glow effect using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to add an "outer glow" Photoshop effect to some text using CSS. Here is a screenshot of the mockup of what I am trying to acheive:

[image]

Here is the Photoshop layer settings:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is `text-shadow` but I've been messing around with it and I cannot achieve a glow on all sides.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Text-shadow` is what you have to use to achieve glow or some kind of text-shadow.

```
p{
text-shadow : horizontal-shadow vertical-shadow blur color;
}
```

To add `multiple text-shadow`, you can do that by separating them, by adding comma to text-shadow property.

```
p{
    text-shadow : horizontal-shadow vertical-shadow blur color, horizontal-shadow vertical-shadow blur color;
 }
```

```css
p{
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 10px #fff, 1px 1px 10px #ccc;
  font-size:48px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<p>
Demo Text
</p>
```

Answer (score 12):

There has `text-shadow`, first two values are `x` and `y` offsets, third value specifies the shadow blur:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 32px black;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}

p {
  margin: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 32px black;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
body{
  background-color: #CCAA77;
}
div{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px white,0px 0px 30px white,0px 0px 30px white,0px 0px 10px #553300,0px 0px 10px #553300;
}
```

```html
<div>Protecting From Cancer</div>
```

As you can see, you can compound several text-shadow to make them more intense and mixing colors.